# Allow self-answered questions on iOS

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, self-answer

Usually when submitting a question there's an "Answer your own question" checkbox.

[image: "Answer your own question" checkbox]

Is there a reason the self-answer option isn't available on the Stack Exchange app for iOS?

Comment: Wait, what? We can't make *selfies* with a mobile?!

Comment: We'd also like it on the Android-app (but there is a tag-limit of 5).

Comment: @Simon the app is totally different, and there should be a separate request for that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this request was mainly about the iOS app, so I'll edit it to be ios specific